# Ethernet connection stopped working

Tags: 12.04, ethernet

I walked away from my computer for a few hours, restarted for some updates and afterwards the ethernet connection was no longer working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I went about solving the problem

1. See if networking is enabled
2. Restart all networking devices
3. Reconfigure ethernet connection
4. Restart SMB / CIFS services
5. Update/Double check nm-settings

---

```
sudo lshw -C network  
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
sudo dhclient eth0 
sudo reload smbd
```

`sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf`

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```