# Ethernet Connection Doesn't work

Tags: 12.04, ethernet

Not sure what happened over the weekend (possibly the last `sudo apt-get upgrade` I ran this morning?), but I noticed that my computer's using my phone's internet connection (connected via USB and listed as "Wired Connection 2") instead of my ethernet connection ("Wired Connection 1").

I've tried restarting NetworkManager with `sudo service network-manager start` and `stop`, but that doesn't appear to fix anything.  Rebooting doesn't change anything either.  Adding my static IP address information to `/etc/network/interfaces` didn't help, so I removed that again.  I tried the steps in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/164483/85023), but that didn't fix it either.

`grep -i eth0 /var/log/syslog` gets me:

```
Oct 15 10:27:30 bdares NetworkManager[772]: <info> (eth0): now managed
Oct 15 10:27:30 bdares NetworkManager[772]: <info> (eth0): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Oct 15 10:27:30 bdares NetworkManager[772]: <info> (eth0): bringing up device.
Oct 15 10:27:30 bdares NetworkManager[772]: <info> (eth0): preparing device.
Oct 15 10:27:30 bdares NetworkManager[772]: <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'managed') [2]
Oct 15 10:27:30 bdares kernel: [   21.419591] r8169 0000:03:00.0: eth0: link down
Oct 15 10:27:30 bdares kernel: [   21.419690] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
```

`ifconfig -a`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:85:a9:96:dc:17  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:43 Base address:0xc000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e6:ce:8f:c3:a2:b1  
          inet addr:172.20.10.2  Bcast:172.20.10.15  Mask:255.255.255.240
          inet6 addr: fe80::e4ce:8fff:fec3:a2b1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1269 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1321 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:635761 (635.7 KB)  TX bytes:189206 (189.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:262 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:262 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:34268 (34.2 KB)  TX bytes:34268 (34.2 KB)
```

Here you can see that my phone is called `eth1`.

What can I do?

Comment: Do you know what could happened over the weekend ? A change (you made or not) to the phone settings for "Internet sharing". I said that cuz I was a "victim" of similar situation. Struggled over 2 hours in Ubuntu to figure out what happened and at the end the phone settings "Internet Share" wasn't enabled. Check it out.

Comment: I logged in this morning with my phone plugged in, saw updates available, and ran them.  Turned on a Chrome window for slashdot.  Then I ssh'd into a local server, noticed it was responding very slowly, and checked the Network Manager GUI and saw that it listed my normal connection as disconnected.  Literally all I did.

Answer (score 1):

Try these following commands as root.

```
ifconfig eth0 x.x.x.x 

route -add default gw x.x.x.y
```

You may also want to run `dmesg` to see if there is more information.

It would be better if we knew which Ubuntu version you use.